# how to show database data from mongoose with express js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i have tried many time but didn't get exact format to show database data in html

i m using hbs as a view engine

and using mongooes mongodb

i have attached the code please mention what am i missing in it

i will be thankful to you

i have tried

<%= name %>

but its giving me errors i dont know how to do it properly i m new to express and tried so many time

here is the code

```
html tag
<p name="name"></p>



router code //
sellerreg.get("/seller",async(req,res)=>{
    const email="abdulsami292@gmail.com";
    const user =await  sellers.findOne({email:email})
   res.render("admin.hbs",{name:email
   })

 })
```

Comment: how did you initialize `sellers`? And, note, you aren't using the results from you query

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: seller is from database (const sellers = require("../module/sellerschema"))

Comment: i m using hbs and i want to show databse data in my hbs file i want to know how can i do that